# How do I get at the underlying Error from an Alamofire error?

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, nserror

**For this request:**

```
Alamofire.request("https://google.com").responseCollection { (response: DataResponse<[User]>) in
  guard response.result.isSuccess else {
    print(response.error)

    return
  }
}
```

**I see this printed in the console:**

> Optional(my_app_name.BackendError.jsonSerialization(Alamofire.AFError.responseSerializationFailed(Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.jsonSerializationFailed(Error
>   Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character
>   0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.}))))

**What I've tried:**

```
Alamofire.request("https://google.com").responseCollection { (response: DataResponse<[User]>) in
  guard response.result.isSuccess else {
    print(response.error)

    if let error1 = response.error as? AFError {
      print(error1)  // Execution DOES NOT reach here.
    }

    if let error2 = response.error as? BackendError {
      print(error2) // Execution DOES reach here.
    }

    return
  }
}
```

`print(error2)` above prints:

> jsonSerialization(Alamofire.AFError.responseSerializationFailed(Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.jsonSerializationFailed(Error
>   Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character
>   0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.})))

**What I'm trying to do is get at the underlying error so I can parse the `domain`, `code`, and `userInfo` properties.**

I created the `BackendError` enum that Alamofire provides as an example at https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#handling-errors :

```
enum BackendError: Error {
    case network(error: Error) // Capture any underlying Error from the URLSession API
    case dataSerialization(error: Error)
    case jsonSerialization(error: Error)
    case xmlSerialization(error: Error)
    case objectSerialization(reason: String)
}
```

and I also implemented the example generic response object serialization exactly like the example at https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#generic-response-object-serialization :

```
extension DataRequest {
  @discardableResult
  func responseCollection<T: ResponseCollectionSerializable>(
    queue: DispatchQueue? = nil,
    completionHandler: @escaping (DataResponse<[T]>) -> Void) -> Self {
    let responseSerializer = DataResponseSerializer<[T]> { request, response, data, error in
      guard error == nil else {
        return .failure(BackendError.network(error: error!))
      }

      let jsonSerializer = DataRequest.jsonResponseSerializer(options: .allowFragments)
      let result = jsonSerializer.serializeResponse(request, response, data, nil)

      guard case let .success(jsonObject) = result else {
        return .failure(BackendError.jsonSerialization(error: result.error!))
      }

      guard let response = response else {
        let reason = "Response collection could not be serialized due to nil response."
        return .failure(BackendError.objectSerialization(reason: reason))
      }

      return .success(T.collection(from: response, withRepresentation: jsonObject))
    }

    return response(responseSerializer: responseSerializer, completionHandler: completionHandler)
  }
}
```

I think there are `switch`es, `case`s, and casts to and from `BackendError`, `AFError`, `Error`, and/or `NSError`, but I can't seem to get it.

**How can I get at the underlying error so I can parse the `domain`, `code`, and `userInfo` properties?**

I'm using Swift 3 and Alamofire 4.3.0 .

Comment: what is the purpose you try to get the invalid response

Comment: I'm trying do something when receiving a specific error.

Comment: this is invalid JSON error also then how will u handle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Alamofire 4.3, look at `response.result`:

```
if case let .failure(error) = response.result {
    let error = error as NSError
    print("\(error.domain)")
    print("\(error.code)")
    print("\(error.userInfo)")
}
```

Comment: this still prints the AF error and not the underlying error. Code is zero, userInfo is empty and localizedDescription is the alamofire text, not the original one from underlying error.

Answer (score 1):

I know the answer is a little late ;-). But try this:

```
... } catch let error as NSError {
print("UnderlyingError: \(String(describing: error.userInfo[NSUnderlyingErrorKey]))")}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
let underlyingError = error.errorUserInfo["NSUnderlyingError"] as! NSError
let code = underlyingError.code
let domain = underlyingError.domain
let userInfo = underlyingError.userInfo
```