# Use of unresolved identifier 'AF' while using Almofire by Swift Package Manager

Tags: ios, swift, swift-package-manager

I am using Almofire through `Swift Package Manager` (SPM) and also imported it by `import Alamofire`. While I am trying to make a network request using `AF`, it gives me following error:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your Swift Package Dependencies seems that you are using Alamofire 4.9.1 and, if i'm not wrong, AF namespace is used from Alamofire 5. So you can switch to Alamofire 5 or change

```
AF.request("url..")...
```

to

```
Alamofire.request("url..")...
```

Comment: Upvoted..I checked it and it is working fine. Why it is version 4.9.1? I just downloaded dependency through Swift package manager an hour ago..

Comment: I think that SPM downloaded 4.9.1 version because 5 is still beta. If you want to download that version, you should specified it. If my answer is correct please, mark it as correct. Thank you

Comment: If you can answer, can you tell me how can I use `.Validate()` of Almofire in best way? e.g. .`validate(statusCode: 200..<300)` or something else

Comment: Check if this my answer to another post can help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/45105730/4205097